# Why upon clicking actionResult the control goes to Get part and not post part of the action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, actionresult

I have this method in controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangeStatus(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
                {
                    InspectionReportDAL = new InspectionReportDAL();
                    User user = (User)Session["User"];

                    InspectionReport InspectionReport = uwork.InspectionReportRepository.GetByID(id);

                    if (id == 1) //Reviewed
                    {
                        InspectionReport.CheckedBy = user.UserID;
                        InspectionReport.Status = (byte) id;
                    }
                    else if (id == 2) //Approved
                    {
                        InspectionReport.ApprovedBy = user.UserID;
                        InspectionReport.Status = (byte)id;
                    }
                    else if (id == 3) //Issued
                    {
                        InspectionReport.IssuedBy = user.UserID;
                        InspectionReport.Status = (byte)id;
                    }

                    uwork.Save();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "InspectionReport");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return View();
            }

        }
```

I am calling it using action link, from an Edit view which uses an action method in the same controller

```
@Html.ActionLink("Review", "ChangeStatus", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

Controller name is **InspectionResult**.

When I click the ActionLink, it goes to the ChangeStatus method but the Get's one not the post's one.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ChangeStatus()

        { return View(); }
```

Route.Config

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Also, ActionLink is inside the

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Update: Full code

```
@model VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities.InspectionReport

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>InspectionReport</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InspectionReportID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VelosiProjectNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VelosiProjectNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VelosiProjectNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VelosiReportNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VelosiReportNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VelosiReportNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reference, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reference, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reference, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PoNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PoNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IssueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionPhase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InspectionPhase, new List<SelectListItem>
                   {
                     new SelectListItem { Text = "Before", Value = "0"},
                     new SelectListItem { Text = "During", Value = "1"},
                     new SelectListItem { Text = "Final", Value = "2"}
                  }, "-Select-",
                  new
                  {
                      @Style = "Width:500px;height:40px;",
                      @class = "form-control input-lg"
                  })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionPhase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InServiceInspection, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InServiceInspection)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InServiceInspection, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewInduction, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewInduction)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewInduction, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HydrostaticTest, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HydrostaticTest)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HydrostaticTest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DimensionalCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DimensionalCheck)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DimensionalCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ThicknessCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThicknessCheck)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ThicknessCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patrom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Patrom)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patrom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gvs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gvs)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gvs, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinalOgraInspection, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FinalOgraInspection)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinalOgraInspection, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OmcClientRequirement, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OmcClientRequirement)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OmcClientRequirement, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TankLorryRegistrationNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TankLorryRegistrationNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TankLorryRegistrationNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TruckTractorManufacturerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TruckTractorManufacturerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TruckTractorManufacturerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Capacity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Capacity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Capacity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Omc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Omc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Omc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EngineNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EngineNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EngineNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TankLorryDimension, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TankLorryDimension, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TankLorryDimension, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChassisNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChassisNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChassisNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionPlace, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionPlace, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionPlace, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TankLorryEnginePower, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TankLorryEnginePower, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TankLorryEnginePower, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarriageName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarriageName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarriageName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brakes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Brakes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brakes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSatisfactory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSatisfactory)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsSatisfactory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remarks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rev, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rev, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rev, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PeparedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PeparedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PeparedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CheckedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CheckedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CheckedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApprovedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApprovedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApprovedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @{
    if (Model.Status == 0)
    {
        @Html.Label("Prepared", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label label-primary" })
    }
    else if (Model.Status == 1)
    {
        @Html.Label("Reviewed", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label label-info" });
    }
    else if (Model.Status == 2)
    {
        @Html.Label("Approved", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label label-success" });
    }
    else if (Model.Status == 3)
    {
        @Html.Label("Issued", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label label-default" });
    }
                }

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-12">

                @{

    VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities.User user = (VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities.User)Session["User"];

    if (user != null)
    {
        if ((user.UserGroupID == 3 || user.UserGroupID == 1) && Model.Status < 1)  //Preparator
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
        }
        else if (user.UserGroupID == 4 && Model.Status == 0)  //Reviewer
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Review", "ChangeStatus", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })

           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
        }
        else if (user.UserGroupID == 1003 && Model.Status == 1)  //Approver
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "ChangeStatus", new { id = 2 }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
        }
        else if (user.UserGroupID == 1004 && Model.Status == 2)  //Issuer
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Issue", "ChangeStatus", new { id = 3 }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
        }
    }
                }


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#IssueDate").datepicker();
        $("#InspectionDate").datepicker();
    });


</script>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: You have to **submit** the form in order to POST; using an action link (even within a form) will result in a GET to that route

Comment: so what's the alternative?

Comment: Instead of using the action link html helper, use an input element with `type=“submit”`, it will automatically result in a POST call to that method

Comment: ok but how would I mention action and controller in that?

Comment: I did but still it doesn't.  <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="location.href= @Url.Action("ChangeStatus", "InspectionReport", new { id= 1 })" class="btn btn-success" />

Comment: you don’t need onclick, but you need to set the desired route destination in the begin form helper `@Html.BeginForm(“actionName”, “controllerName”)`.

Comment: You can't use an ActionLink for POST method

Comment: @DavideVitali: i used beginform but still doesn't work

Comment: using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeStatus", "InspectionReport", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeStatus", "InspectionReport", FormMethod.Post)) 
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            }

Comment: @DavideVitali: hi i have posted my full code. i tried my best but nothing works

Comment: even if i put the link manually into the browser like this http://localhost:46524/InspectionReport/ChangeStatus/1

Comment: it doesn't hit the action. why?

Answer (score 1):

Well what you can try out is comment out the **@Html.BeginForm() and it's two braces {}** and then try to hit your change status method with 
`@Html.ActionLink("InspectionResult", "ChangeStatus", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })`
I had a similar issue before where BeginForm was trying to hit my get method after the post method and reloading the form.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks for your help guys.

But I figured it out.

This worked.

```
 <button type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" formaction='@Url.Action("ChangeStatus", "InspectionReport", new { id = 1, recordID = Model.InspectionReportID })'>Save</button>
```

Comment: great. Just make sure once by debugging whether after your post request, it doesn't go the get method again.

Comment: I just deleted the get method.